# JSON to display head and sublist as output

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Built a code to display value from JSON format to HTML output. When its without sublevel it works fine. As per new requirement, need to display "TestEle1, TestEle2" as header. Sub level elements as checkbox with label.

This is the present code used to display single level JSON format to HTML output.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
 <@
 _.each(data,function(value, key, list){
 @>
 <input id="<@= value.filtername @>" class="" type="checkbox" name="<@= value.filtername @>" value="<@= value.filtervalue @>"><label id="label-<@= value.filtername @>" for="<@= value.filtername @>"> <span class="filterlabel"><@= value.filterlabel @></span></label>
 <@
 });
 @>
</div>
```

**JSON:**

```
[   
"TestEle1":[  
  {  
     filtername:'test1',
     filterlabel:'Test1',
     filtervalue:'test1'
  },
  {  
     filtername:'test2',
     filterlabel:'Test2',
     filtervalue:'test2'
  }
  ],
  "TestEle2":[  
  {  
     filtername:'test3',
     filterlabel:'Test3',
     filtervalue:'test3'
  },
  {  
     filtername:'test4',
     filterlabel:'Test4',
     filtervalue:'test4'
  }
 ]
]
```

Output (In front of Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4 have checkbox):

```
TestEle1
  Test1
  Test2

TestEle2
  Test3
  Test4
```

Comment: Posting the `html` makes sense to your question!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JSON is not valid .correct form

```
[ 
        {
                    "TestEle1":[
                        {
                            "filtername":"test1",
                            "filterlabel":"Test1",
                            "filtervalue":"test1"
                        },
                        {
                            "filtername":"test2",
                            "filterlabel":"Test2",
                            "filtervalue":"test2"
                        }
                    ]
        },
        {
                    "TestEle2":[
                        {
                            "filtername":"test3",
                            "filterlabel":"Test3",
                            "filtervalue":"test3"
                        },
                        {
                            "filtername":"test4",
                            "filterlabel":"Test4",
                            "filtervalue":"test4"
                        }
                    ]
       }
]
```

Try with this code. Although i am not sure about the template syntax you used for this.

```
<div class="container">
     <@
     _.each(data,function(val1, key1){
     @>
       <@  _.each(val1,function(val,key){ 
        @>
           <h3><@= key @></h3>    // title value 
            <@  _.each(val,function(value,index){ 
              @>
          <input id="<@= value.filtername @>" class="" type="checkbox" name="<@= value.filtername @>" value="<@= value.filtervalue @>"><label id="label-<@= value.filtername @>" for="<@= value.filtername @>"> <span class="filterlabel"><@= value.filterlabel @></span></label>
    <@  }); 
    @>
     <hr>   
      });
     });
     @>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Hitman, Thanks for sharing your answer. But, its not working with my existing JSON format. Is it possible to change JSON format to work with present script? In addition we need to add Titlehead "TestEle1, TestEle2". which not added on present code.

Comment: Thanks Hitman.. Almost done. only <h3>Key</h3> displays handcoded value.

Comment: sorry template syntax error. modified check. please vote if you are satisfied.

Comment: Thanks.. 1 last question.. if i want to add <hr> in between two container. is it possible?